# Sieve of Sundaram

Tags: c, primes

Every integer can be written in the form \$2^i*v\$ where \$v\$ is odd. This algorithm generates a list of numbers that are only odd. We want to ensure that all the composite odd numbers are marked out.

In the final list, all numbers will be of the form \$2^0 v\$. So, we only need to worry about odd factors. An odd number will be composite if it is of the form \$(2i + 1)(2j + 1)\$, where \$i\$ and \$j\$ are strictly positive integers. So, a composite odd number \$q = 2k + 1 = 4ij + 2i + 2j + 1\$. This means \$k = i + j + 2ij\$. Whenever \$k\$ is of the form, \$i + j + 2ij, 2k+ 1\$ is composite and whenever an odd integer \$q\$ is composite, the condition holds for \$k, q = 2k + 1\$.

All we seek to do is mark all numbers that can be written as \$i +j + 2ij\$. And for any unmarked integer \$k\$, we know that \$2k + 1\$ will be prime. Note - We need to hardcode `2` since this algorithm *only* generates the odd primes.

Please provide feedback.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define target 50000

//Function prototypes
void initial_marking(long int[]);
void marking(long int[]);
void make_prime_list(long int[],long int[]);
void print_prime(long int[]);

int main()
{
    //Half of the numbers from 1 to target will be even so the number of primes will never exceed target/2.
    //The algorithm only worries about the first half of the range. That's why list also goes till target/2.
    long list[target/2], primes[target/2];

    //Sieve of Sundaram
    initial_marking(list);
    //Crossing out all numbers of the form i + j + 2ij
    marking(list);

    //Making the list of primes
    make_prime_list(primes, list);

    //Displaying the list
    print_primes(primes);

    return 0;
}

//Initially, everything is marked 1
void initial_marking(long int list[])
{
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i <= target/2; i++)
    {
        list[i] = 1;
    }
}

//Crossing out numbers of the form i + j + 2ij
void marking(long int list[])
{
    int i, j, crossed_out_num;

    //All numbers of the form i + j + 2ij need to be marked out
    for(i = 1; i <= target/2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            crossed_out_num = i + j + 2*i*j;

            if(crossed_out_num <= target/2)//If this condition isn't there, we might me marking numbers not in list.
            {
                list[crossed_out_num] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}   

//Making the list of primes
void make_prime_list(long int primes[],long int list[])
{
    int i = 0, primeCount = 0;

    //We need to put 2 in ourselves because the algorithm 'only' generates all the odd primes
    primes[primeCount++] = 2;
    for(i = 1; i <= target/2; i++)
    {
        //Checking if the number is not crossed out and adding 2i + 1 to the list if it is unmarked.
        if(list[i] == 1)
        {
            primes[primeCount++] = (2*i + 1);
        }
    }   

    //Putting 0 to mark the end of the array
    primes[primeCount] = 0;
}   

void print_primes(long int primes[])
{
    int i;

    //0 indicates the end of the array
    for(i = 0; primes[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        printf("%ld\t",primes[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let \$f(i,j) = i + j + 2ij\$

Then \$f(i,j+1) = i + j + 1 + 2i(j+1) = i+j+2ij+2i+1 = f(i,j)+2i+1\$

Using this, the `marking()` function (which is the highest complexity function) can be rewritten as such:

```
void marking(long int list[])
{
    long long int i, crossed_out_num, i_limit, cross_limit, increment;
    i_limit = target/6; // i > i_limit will never give f(i,j) in range

    //All numbers of the form i + j + 2ij need to be marked out
    for(i = 1; i <= i_limit; i++)
    {
        increment = 2*i + 1;

        // f(i,j) <= target/2 and j <= i
        cross_limit = target/2;
        if(cross_limit > 2*i*(i+1)) cross_limit = 2*i*(i+1);

        // Find crossed_out_num directly by starting with j=1 and using the above result
        for(crossed_out_num = 3*i + 1; crossed_out_num <= cross_limit; crossed_out_num += increment)
        {
            list[crossed_out_num] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This should speed up the code considerably and avoid overflow when `i` becomes large.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at target/6 ? I also have another question. My program seems to work till limit is 60 thousand but doesn't work when I set limit greater than that. Is it because of time complexity or because of something else ? Like array being too large or something

Comment: For a given value of i, the smallest value of f(i,j) is 3i+1. We want it to be less than target/2, hence the limit of imax=target/6. By "doesn't work" do you mean wrong answer or crash? If wrong answer that might be because of i*j overflow. Crash would be because you are allocating array memory in main() so it goes to stack. Either move the arrays global or use heap-based allocation using malloc().

Comment: I'll try moving it to main. Thanks. Are you a mathematician ?

Comment: Can you explain why declaring it in main would cause a problem

Comment: Putting it in global doesn't work. Advise me about the heap based allocation.

Comment: If global didn't work, neither will heap. Can you describe the exact problem that you have? (I am not a mathematician, I am a physicist and a bit of a programmer).

Comment: Okay ... I'll check what heap is. Physics is cool. The problem is ... The program as it is now works fine if I change limit to 60 thousand but crashes if I make limit 70 thousand. I need to make limit a million because I want to generate a list of the first ten thousand primes. I

Comment: Do you mind trying my program on your computer and changing the limit to see how high you can increase limit before crashing ? I am unsure if the crashing is because of an algorithmic reason (too slow) or because of something to do with the language like array size ... Please help.

Comment: Tried on my comp. Your code fails for 70000 because of overflow I think. Replacing your `marking()` function with my function in the answer fixes it.

Comment: What kind of overflow ? Is it an issue of space or time ? I'll try reading and understanding your code in the morning again. It's a bit tough.

Comment: Integer overflow. The mistake was using `int` for variables inside `marking()` instead of `long`. I would use `long long` to be sure.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked ! Is this kind of code more efficient in other languages like Python where programmers don't need to worry about overflow ?

Comment: Can you explain why 3i +1 is the smallest value of f(I,j) ?

Comment: Put j=1, should give you the lowest value. Python is not going to be more efficient.

Comment: That's brilliant ! Can you explain why you wrote that if condition for cross_limit ? I don't know why you made it equal to $2i(I+1)$?

Comment: Put $j=i$ and you get that

Answer (score 3):

### Check your types

> ```
>     long list[target/2], primes[target/2];
> ```

Elsewhere it's `long int`, here it's `long`. Be consistent.

`list` only ever contains values `0` and `1`. Ideally it would use a 1-bit integer type (and you could consider writing a basic bitset implementation if it's not in the library). It's certainly wasteful to use `long int`.

Integer types in C are a mess, which is why `<stdint.h>` was created. This might be controversial, but my opinion is that code written after the year 2000 should use `int`, `long int`, `long long int`, etc. *only* when *required* to do so for compatibility with older libraries.

The primes will never be negative, so it makes more sense to use unsigned types than signed.

### Don't reinvent the wheel

`initial_marking` is unnecessary. With C-99 you could just initialise `list` as `{}` to set them all to `0` and reverse the meaning of the mark; with legacy versions of C you could use `memset` to set them all to `1`.

### Check your edge conditions

> ```
>             if(crossed_out_num <= target/2)//If this condition isn't there, we might me marking numbers not in list.
>             {
>                 list[crossed_out_num] = 0;
>             }
> ```

`list` was initialised as `long list[target/2]`. C uses 0-indexing. So that condition should be `< target/2`, not `<= target/2`: as it stands, it can access memory beyond the end of the array.

In this particular case you probably get away with it, because the following chunk of memory probably belongs to `primes`, but that's not something it's wise to rely on.

There is a similar bug in `make_prime_list`.

### Use descriptive names

The name `list` tells me nothing that I wouldn't already know from the type (i.e. that it's an array). What do the elements of the array mean? In this case it seems to be `is_prime` (or `is_half_prime` if you want to be pedantic).

`marking` isn't as bad, but is still fairly undescriptive. `sieve` would be an improvement; `sundaram_sieve` would be better still.

`print_primes`, on the other hand, goes too far. There's nothing in the implementation which limits it to printing primes. It's really `print_integers`.

### Do you need to statically allocate so much memory?

The number of primes will indeed never exceed `target/2`, but you could go further and observe that they will never exceed `2 + target/3` (by considerations of values modulo 6), etc. However, the sieve tells you how many primes there are before you try to extract them. Consider this simple modification:

```
size_t sundaram_sieve(uint8_t is_prime[])
{
    size_t primeCount = 1; // Allow for the special case 2
    uint32_t i, delta, composite;

    //All numbers of the form i + j + 2ij need to be marked out
    for (i = 1; i < target/2; i++)
    {
        primeCount += is_prime[i];

        delta = 2*i + 1;
        for (composite = 2*i*(i+1); composite < target/2; composite += delta)
        {
            is_prime[composite] = 0;
        }
    }

    return primeCount;
}
```

Now `primes` can be `calloc`ed to exactly the size required.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the new data types and that you can initialize the entire array at once. I don't recognize the data types you use at the end. What are they ?

Comment: Do you recommend using the byte data type for list ?

Comment: @user230452, I really recommend writing a bitset implementation as a good exercise, but in the example refactor I've used `uint8_t`, which is a byte datatype on most modern architectures. The types I've used are (mainly) those from [`<stdint.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html); `size_t` is the exception, and that's because it's intended as a parameter to [`calloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/calloc.html).

Comment: Are you a programmer ? Can you explain what a bit set is ? Is it a binary array ?

Comment: I am. Yes, a bitset is basically a binary array. The typical implementation would be to have an array of some integer type (e.g. `uint8_t[]` or `uint32_t[]`) and to set/clear/test individual bits.

Comment: Is C programming a part of your job ? Many teachers here say that C is no longer used in real companies.

Comment: @user230452, the only time I've used C "professionally" was a summer internship back in 2001 (hence the scare quotes: I was paid, but I wasn't yet a professional).

Comment: Wow. I will post more solutions in C to Project Euler questions. Please provide your feedback in future as well.